# How to get values from resultset which satisfies some condition and display that in table

Tags: java, mysql

I have a method which displays the values in a table where I have the latest time.The code for this method is:

```js
public String[][] beamline_Status() {
  int i = 0;
  try

  {
    con = getConnection();
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT TOP 1 c.logtime, a.BL1_data_SS_ST,a.BL2_data_SS_ST,a.BL3_data_SS_ST,a.BL4_data_SS_ST,a.BL5_data_SS_ST,a.BL6_data_SS_ST,a.BL7_data_SS_ST,a.BL8_data_SS_ST,a.BL9_data_SS_ST,a.BL10_data_SS_ST,a.BL11_data_SS_ST, a.BL12_data_SS_ST,a.BL13_data_SS_ST,a.BL14_data_SS_ST,a.BL15_data_SS_ST,a.BL16_data_SS_ST,a.BL17_data_SS_ST,a.BL18_data_SS_ST,a.BL19_data_SS_ST,a.BL20_data_SS_ST,a.BL21_data_SS_ST,a.BL22_data_SS_ST,a.BL23_data_SS_ST,a.BL24_data_SS_ST,a.BL25_data_SS_ST,a.BL26_data_SS_ST,a.BL27_data_SS_ST,b.st1_prmt_status_p45,c.beam_current,c.beam_energy from INDUS2_BLFE.dbo.main_BLFE_status a inner join INDUS2_MSIS.dbo.main_MSIS_status b on a.logtime=b.logtime inner join INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT c on b.logtime=c.logtime ORDER BY c.logtime DESC ";

    stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();

    while (rs.next()) {

      for (int j = 0; j < 31; j++) {
        a[i][j] = rs.getString(j + 1);

      }


    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("\nException in  Bean " +e.getMessage());
  } finally {
    closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
  }

  return a;



}
```

This method returns correct result.

Now I have another method from which I want to retrieve only those column values where 1 is present and three other columns from the resultset which shows the time and beam_energy and beam_current values and display those values in a table with there respective column name.The code for the method is:

```js
public List < Integer > beam_CurrentStatus() throws SQLException {

  try

  {
    con = getConnection();
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT TOP 1 c.logtime, a.BL1_data_SS_ST,a.BL2_data_SS_ST,a.BL3_data_SS_ST,a.BL4_data_SS_ST,a.BL5_data_SS_ST,a.BL6_data_SS_ST,a.BL7_data_SS_ST,a.BL8_data_SS_ST,a.BL9_data_SS_ST,a.BL10_data_SS_ST,a.BL11_data_SS_ST, a.BL12_data_SS_ST,a.BL13_data_SS_ST,a.BL14_data_SS_ST,a.BL15_data_SS_ST,a.BL16_data_SS_ST,a.BL17_data_SS_ST,a.BL18_data_SS_ST,a.BL19_data_SS_ST,a.BL20_data_SS_ST,a.BL21_data_SS_ST,a.BL22_data_SS_ST,a.BL23_data_SS_ST,a.BL24_data_SS_ST,a.BL25_data_SS_ST,a.BL26_data_SS_ST,a.BL27_data_SS_ST,b.st1_prmt_status_p45,c.beam_current,c.beam_energy from INDUS2_BLFE.dbo.main_BLFE_status a inner join INDUS2_MSIS.dbo.main_MSIS_status b on a.logtime=b.logtime inner join INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT c on b.logtime=c.logtime ORDER BY c.logtime DESC ";

    stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();

    while (rs.next()) {


      for (int j = 2; j < 30; j++) {
        if (rs.getInt(j) == 1)

          al.add(rs.getInt(j));
      }


    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\nException in  Bean " + e.getMessage());
  } finally {
   closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
  }


  return al;


}
```

This method returns only 1 as many times 1 is present in table , the output is

> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

But I want this to be shown along with column name in tabular format.How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a `Map<String, Integer>` to get `String` and `Integer`. And, you could use the [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) to get the column label. Something like,

```
public Map<String, Integer> beam_CurrentStatus() throws SQLException {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        con = getConnection();
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        String sql = "SELECT TOP 1 c.logtime, a.BL1_data_SS_ST,a.BL2_data_SS_ST,a.BL3_data_SS_ST,a.BL4_data_SS_ST,a.BL5_data_SS_ST,a.BL6_data_SS_ST,a.BL7_data_SS_ST,a.BL8_data_SS_ST,a.BL9_data_SS_ST,a.BL10_data_SS_ST,a.BL11_data_SS_ST, a.BL12_data_SS_ST,a.BL13_data_SS_ST,a.BL14_data_SS_ST,a.BL15_data_SS_ST,a.BL16_data_SS_ST,a.BL17_data_SS_ST,a.BL18_data_SS_ST,a.BL19_data_SS_ST,a.BL20_data_SS_ST,a.BL21_data_SS_ST,a.BL22_data_SS_ST,a.BL23_data_SS_ST,a.BL24_data_SS_ST,a.BL25_data_SS_ST,a.BL26_data_SS_ST,a.BL27_data_SS_ST,b.st1_prmt_status_p45,c.beam_current,c.beam_energy from INDUS2_BLFE.dbo.main_BLFE_status a inner join INDUS2_MSIS.dbo.main_MSIS_status b on a.logtime=b.logtime inner join INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT c on b.logtime=c.logtime ORDER BY c.logtime DESC ";

        stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int j = 2; j < 30; j++) {
                if (rs.getInt(j) == 1) {
                    String name = rsmd.getColumnLabel(j);
                    map.put(name, rs.getInt(j));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("\nException in  Bean " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: I got the values along with column names but I need to add three more columns from resultset with there values .Moreover i want to display it in tabular format and sequence or order is not proper.

Comment: The code I posted will get all unique column names and their values. If you need duplicate column names you'll need to create a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) and return a `List` of them. `LinkedHashMap` would preserve order. The above should be more than enough for you to get started.

Comment: For order I have used LinkedHashMap.But how to add those three columns in it..??

Comment: @SRY_JAVA **What** three columns? Change the label. Or make a POJO.

Comment: Apart from these columns which are displayed where value is 1, I want three more columns which have values as **2014-09-02 16:05:10.000**, **110.58**,**2500.0635**

Comment: @SRY_JAVA That's a new question. Especially since you said you want values where the value **is** `1`. Even more so since those values aren't integer(s).

Comment: you are correct those values are not integers.But can you please tell me how to add these values into map???

Comment: Try a `Map<String, String>`. Or make a POJO.

Comment: Can I define my own column name inspite of using from table,if yes how??

Comment: `SELECT c.logtime MY_NAME` or `SELECT c.logtime AS MY_OTHER_NAME`